# is this boost::tuple code convertible to pure std:: standard library code?

Tags: c++, boost, stl, c++11, std

*Is the following boost code convertible to pure c++11 standard libraries?*

I see `std::tuple` and `std::for_each` but I can't seem to get them to play with each other.

I am currently using gcc 4.7.2.

**CODE**

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/fusion/algorithm/iteration/for_each.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/boost_tuple.hpp>

struct DoOutput
{
    template<typename T>
    void operator()(T const& t) const
    {
            std::cerr << t << std::endl;
    }

    void operator()(std::string const& t) const
    {
            std::cerr << "'" << t << "'" << std::endl;
    }
};

int
main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    boost::tuple< std::string, int > t = boost::make_tuple( "foo", 42 );
    boost::fusion::for_each( t, DoOutput() );

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

No, the code is not directly convertible.

Boost.Fusion is a library for working with tuples, so its `for_each` works with tuples, i.e. a structure with zero or more heterogeneous types.  `std::for_each` works with iterator ranges, which are ranges of values of homogeneous type.

Using something like [index_tuple.h](http://gitorious.org/redistd/redistd/blobs/master/include/redi/index_tuple.h) you can change it to this:

```
struct sink {
  template<typename... T>
    sink(T&&...) { }
};

template<typename T, typename F>
  int apply(T&& t, F& f)
  {
    f(std::forward<T>(t));
    return 0;
  }

template<typename Tuple, typename F, unsigned... Indices>
  void apply(Tuple&& t, F&& f, index_tuple<Indices...>)
  {
    sink{ apply(std::get<Indices>(std::forward<Tuple>(t)), f)... };
  }

int main()
{
  std::tuple< std::string, int > t = std::make_tuple( "foo", 42 );
  apply(t, DoOutput(), make_index_tuple<std::tuple_size<decltype(t)>::value>::type() );
}
```

This creates a type `index_tuple<0,1>` and calls `apply`, which deduces the parameter pack `Indices` as `{0, 1}` and then expands that pack as:

```
sink{ apply(std::get<0>(t), f), apply(std::get<1>(t), f) };
```

where `f` is a function object of type `DoOutput`, and each apply calls `f(tn)`

Initializing the temporary `sink` is only needed because you can't expand a parameter pack in an expression, e.g. this isn't valid:

```
    f(std::get<Indices>(t))...;
```

So instead the pack is expanded as the initializer list to an object's constructor, which also guarantees that each element of the pack expansion is evaluated in order.

Comment: `std::get<i>(t)` will not compile. `i` needs to be compile-time constant.

Comment: @Nawaz +1 that's what I thought, too

Comment: Note that (I believe) this does not guarantee the order in which `f` gets applied to the tuple elements.

Comment: Another issue: it won't work when `f` returns `void`, as it does above.

Comment: @interjay, I thought that a pack expansion is evaluated in order, even as a function argument list (which normally has unspecified order of eval) but I can't find that rule now, so I guess it isn't.  Revising the code again, and I'll actually test it this time!

Comment: fixed with a level of indirection and using the pack expansion as an init list (which does evaluate left to right) instead of function argument list

Comment: @Jonathan : §14.5.3/6 seems to imply that pack expansion is evaluated in order.

Comment: @ildjarn, that just says it produces an argument list for the function, not which order the arguments are evaluated in after the pack is expanded. Clang++ evaluates left to right but G++ doesn't.

Comment: @Jonathan : Ahh, gotcha, I see now.

Comment: I don't recommend to use an array for this purpose, because you cannot have a declared empty array. I.e if you pass an empty tuple, your code errors out. I recommend to do the pack expansion using a `sink` type, as `struct sink { template<typename T> sink(T...){} };` because it both allows you to use an init list (so evaluation order is left to right) and it allows an empty expansion: `sink{ apply(std::get<Indices>(std::forward<Tuple>(t)), f)... };`.

Comment: Very good point, @Johannes, thanks. (It also avoids a warning about an unused variable). Edited. Again.

Comment: I like `template<class T> using Alias = T;` for creating temporary arrays and just stuffing in an element at the beginning of the initializer. `Alias<int[]>{0, apply(xxx)...};`.

Answer (score 1):

No. The C++11 standard library does not include the capabilities of `boost::fusion`. The best that you can hope for is to adapt `std::tuple` to work with `boost::fusion`:

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

#include <tuple>

#include <boost/fusion/algorithm/iteration/for_each.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/std_tuple.hpp> //This feature is undocumented

struct DoOutput
{
    template<typename T>
    void operator()(T const& t) const
    {
            std::cerr << t << std::endl;
    }

    void operator()(std::string const& t) const
    {
            std::cerr << "'" << t << "'" << std::endl;
    }
};

int
main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    std::tuple< std::string, int > t = std::make_tuple( "foo", 42 );
    boost::fusion::for_each( t, DoOutput() );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The feature is now documented: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/adapted/std__tuple.html